# Stack/Cabal cannot find happy

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I'm trying to build [the code from PCPH](https://github.com/simonmar/parconc-examples) using Haskell Stack. However, I'm getting an error about Cabal not finding `happy`. I *have* installed `alex` and `happy` though (they're in `/usr/bin`).

```
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3: The program 'happy' is required but it
could not be found

--  While building package parconc-examples-0.4.3 using:
```

Here's what stack thinks my `PATH` is:

```
$ stack exec bash
$ echo $PATH | tr : '\n'
/home/steshaw/Projects/parconc-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3/bin
/home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3/bin
/home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/bin
/home/steshaw/.nix-profile/bin
/home/steshaw/.nix-profile/sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

Here's the output from `stack path`:

```
stack-root: /home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack
project-root: /home/steshaw/Projects/parconc-examples
config-location: /home/steshaw/Projects/parconc-examples/stack.yaml
bin-path: /home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3/bin:/home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/bin:/home/steshaw/.nix-profile/bin:/home/steshaw/.nix-profile/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
programs: /home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux
compiler-exe: /home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc
compiler-bin: /home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/bin
local-bin: /home/steshaw/.local/bin
extra-include-dirs: 
extra-library-dirs: 
snapshot-pkg-db: /home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3/pkgdb
local-pkg-db: /home/steshaw/Projects/parconc-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3/pkgdb
global-pkg-db: /home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/package.conf.d
ghc-package-path: /home/steshaw/Projects/parconc-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3/pkgdb:/home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3/pkgdb:/home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/package.conf.d
snapshot-install-root: /home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3
local-install-root: /home/steshaw/Projects/parconc-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3
snapshot-doc-root: /home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3/doc
local-doc-root: /home/steshaw/Projects/parconc-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3/doc
dist-dir: .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0
local-hpc-root: /home/steshaw/Projects/parconc-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-4.2/7.10.3/hpc
local-bin-path: /home/steshaw/.local/bin
ghc-paths: /home/steshaw/Projects/shelly/dotfiles/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux
```

Here's the version of happy that stack finds on my path:

```
$ stack exec -- happy -V
Happy Version 1.19.5 Copyright (c) 1993-1996 Andy Gill, Simon Marlow (c) 1997-2005 Simon Marlow

Happy is a Yacc for Haskell, and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms given in the file 'LICENSE' distributed with
the Happy sources.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (x86_64).

Comment: Could you give us the output of `stack exec "echo $path" `?

Comment: That command doesn't quite work but let me try something

Comment: I think this incorrect - you are starting a bash and therefore you load stuff from the global and local bash config. but I checked - there is a `stack path` command that should list the interesting stuff.

Comment: Well it wasn't clear what you mean by `stack exec "echo $path"` :). I'll add the output from `stack path` too.

Comment: hmm - `/usr/bin/` is in your path - can you try `stack exec -- happy -v` - I am usually using the system ghc, but I don't know whether this is related to the problem

Comment: Okay, I've updated with `happy -V`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to try:

1. Install happy via stack using the resolver for the project:

   ```
   stack install happy --resolver lts-4.2
   ```

When I built parconc-examples with resolver lts-4.2 I found that it
was using the happy binary in the lts-4.2 snapshot directory even though
I had it installed elsewhere in my PATH.

2. Use this Setup.hs program:

   ```
   import Distribution.Simple
   import System.Environment

   main = do
     args <- getArgs
     let args' = if elem "configure" args
                   then args ++ [ "--with-happy=/usr/bin/happy" ]
                   else args
     defaultMainWithArgs args'
   ```

And also be sure to change the `build-type:` in parconc-examples.cabal to `Custom`. Completely remove the .stack-work directory to make sure everything gets rebuilt with the new Setup program.

Comment: Installing `happy` via `stack` didn't resolve my problem. It installed the same version of `happy` into ~/.local/bin.

Comment: Try method #2. On my system I have happy installed in ~/.stack/snapshots/$ARCH/$RESOLVER/bin  for various values of $RESOLVER (e.g. lts-4.2, lts-6.0, ...) What version of stack are you running?

Comment: Also just try copying a happy binary into ~/.stack/snapshots/.../lts-4.2/bin

Comment: Yep, trying method #2 now. In the meantime, I have found a solution of adding `build-tools: alex, happy` to the .cabal file for the executable that needs it but I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: Argh! Now I cannot even reproduce the problem. Thanks for your help though!